# Optimization with both equality and inequality constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, self-learning

I need to minimize the following quantity:

$$\min x_1^{-1/n}- \left(1-x_2 \right)^{-1/n}$$

subject to:

$1-x_1-x_2=\gamma$ **and** $0<x_1+x_2<1$

$\gamma$  being a constant.

Had it been two equality constraints the problem could have been easily solved using two Lagrangian multipliers but how do I proceed now?

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you don't need  the inequality constraint here. The first constraint under the condition that $0<\gamma<1$  is enough. It guarantees that the second constraint is satisfied. Moreover you can replace $x_2=(1-x_1-\gamma)$ and solve unconstraint optimization.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Right. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Well the problem I encounter is that $x_1$ vanishes and you get the strange result $0=\gamma$ in both cases. Something I am doing wrong there?

Comment: Use Kuhn-Tucker conditions.  roughly, these say the lagrange multiplier is zero if the inequality constraint is not binding. And it might be easier to write the inequality constraint as two separate constraints.

Comment: How you can get $\gamma=0$  if this is a constant? The problem can be not well defined anyway since you do put constraint $0<x_1$ , $0<x_2$. Or you allow $x_1$,$x_2$ be negative ?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Both are nonnegative. What result are you getting? If you like, you can post an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as I said the inequality constraint can be removed. And moreover we can replace $x_2=1-\gamma-x_1$. So we got unconstrained optimization problem (taking in account that $x_1>0$,$x_2<1$,however,though this is automatically constrained via property of the utility function. 
So we have to optimize 
$$
\min x_1^{-1/n}-(\gamma+x_1)^{-1/n}
$$
So making simple derivative we obtain
$$
-1/n ( x_1^{-\frac{n+1}{n}}- (\gamma+x_1)^{-\frac{n+1}{n}})
$$
Obviously this derivative is always negative since $\gamma>0$. Thus actually 
the problem does not have a mininum. It asympotically tends to 0 as $x_1\to\infty$ and $x_2=1-\gamma - x_1$.
But... I am not sure that this what you wanted. If say you want to bound $x_1$ by $1$. The infimum $1-(\gamma+1)^{-1/n}$ will be achieved with $x_1\to 1$.